# Cocos compile --android-studio

Tags: cocos2d-x

cocos2d-x 3.14.1, ndk r13b

'Standard' compile command works fine:

> cocos compile -p android -m debug --ap android-23

I get an apparent link error when I compile using this command:

> cocos compile -p android -m debug --ap android-23 **--android-studio**

Error:
jni/../../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp:289: error: undefined reference to 'MainMenu::createScene()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libMyGame.so] Error 1
Error running command, return code: 2.

Struggling with this - any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you haven't added the MainMenu class in Android.mk for Android Studio.
Open the android.mk from following path:

> ~project-directory/proj.android-studio/app/jni/android.mk

Add all the classes that you have in the following manner:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
                   ../../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
                   ../../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp
```

Note: Edit the above classes with your actual names.HelloWorldScene.cpp is just used for representation purposes.

Comment: Thank you, yes, I had (rather stupidly) neglected to update my proj.android-studio/app/jni/Android.mk & Application.mk file.

I also guess I need to copy across my res files
 
proj.android/res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png
...

proj.android/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/icon.png

to

proj.android-studio/app/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png...

proj.android-studio/app/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png

???

Anything else I should remember not to forget?

Thanks for the pointer.